# Using AWS Autoscaling as dispatcher

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been given the business logic of

1. A customer makes a request for services through a third party
   gateway GUI to an EC2 instance
2. Processing for some time (15hr)
3. Data retrieval

Currently this is implemented by statically giving each user an EC2 instance to use to handle their requests. (This instance actually creates some sub instances to parallel process the data).

What should happen is that for each request, an EC2 instance be fired off automatically.

In the long term, I was thinking that this should be done using SWF (given the use of sub processes), however, I wondered if as a quick and dirty solution, using Autoscaling with the correct settings is worthwhile pursuing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you can "trick" autoscalling to spin up instances based on metrics:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/policy_creating.html

So on each request, keep track/increments a metric. Decrement the metric when the process completes. Drive the autoscalling group on the metric.

Use Step Adjustments to control the number of instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html#as-scaling-types

Interesting challenges: binding customers to specific EC2 instances. Do you have this hard requirement of giving each customer their own instance? Sounds like autos calling is actually better suited for the paralleling process of the actual data, not for requests routing. You may get away with having a fixed number of machines for this and/or scale based on traffic, not number of customers.